# Java+Jackson で json 文字列から object を生成する際、特定プロパティを文字列のままとしたい

Tags: java, json, jackson

Java+Jackson で json 文字列から object を生成する際、特定プロパティを
文字列のままとしたいのですが、そのようなことは可能でしょうか。

例えば

```
String text =
  "{" +
  "  \"key1\": \"var1\", " +
  "  \"key2\": {\"subkey1\":\"subvar1\", \"subkey2\":\"subvar2\"} " +
  "}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> json = (Map<String, Object>) mapper.readValue(text, Map.class);
```

としたとき、

```
json.get("key1") → var1 という String を取得
json.get("key2") → {"subkey1":"subvar1", "subkey2":"subvar2"} という String を取得
```

としたいのです。

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations
Jackson Annotations 
から、これだ！というのは見つけられていないのですが、おそらく何かしらありそうな気がします。

もしない場合、一度オブジェクトに変換した key2 の値を、再度 json 文字列に
変換する予定ですが、おそらくパフォーマンス的に厳しいことになりそうなので、
Jackson で例外扱いできないかと思っております。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `JsonUtil`というのは自作のクラスですか？でれば、その実装も載せて下さい。

Comment: typo:「でれば、」→「であれば、」です（上の私のコメント）。

Comment: 大変失礼いたしました！自作クラスでした。
コードを自作クラスを使わない形に修正しました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@JsonSetter`を使うと、うまくいくと思います。おそらくこのような感じで

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Sample {
    public String key1;
    public String key2;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String jsonStr = "{" + "  \"key1\": \"var1\", "
                + "  \"key2\": {\"subkey1\":\"subvar1\", \"subkey2\":\"subvar2\"} " + "}";
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Sample json = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, Sample.class);
        System.out.println(json.key2);
    }

    @JsonSetter("key2")
    void setKey2(JsonNode key2) {
        this.key2 = key2.toString();
    }
}
```

この実行結果は以下のようになります。

```
{"subkey1":"subvar1","subkey2":"subvar2"}
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。後は自分で頑張ってみます。